# Attempting to program an HP bar for a WoW addon (.lua)

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I'm in the midst of making a WoW addon for RP'ers and I have come across a bit of a difficult problem. I've written up this addon to have a Health indicator, and a Barrier indicator. The Barrier takes any damage before damage is applied to health, and even carries over if there is a remainder

Bob has 3 Barrier and 10 HP, he takes 4 damage so he now has 9 HP.

I've decided to add another layer of protection, which is Armor. This armor would act as another static healthbar that protect the players HP value.

So Bob has 3 Barrier, 5 Armor and 10 HP. He then takes 4 damage, and now has 0 Barrier, 4 Armor and 10 HP. Then he takes 5 Damage, and now has 0 Barrier, 0 Armor and 9 HP.

All of this would be typed out into the chat of whatever group was appropriate, like this

[image]

I'm having issues implimenting this armor bar, this is what I have so far.

```
        apdmg = 0
        hpdmg = 0
        bdmg = 0
        if TempHP >=0 then hpdmg = tdmg - TempHP
            else hpdmg = tdmg - apdmg end
        if hpdmg < 0 then hpdmg = 0 end
        if apdmg < 0 then hpdmg = 0 end
        bdmg =  tdmg - hpdmg
        tdmg - ArmorPoints = apdmg
        TempHP = TempHP - bdmg
        HealthPoints = HealthPoints - hpdmg
        ArmorPoints = ArmorPoints - apdmg
        if ArmorPoints < 0 then ArmorPoints = 0 end
        if HealthPoints < 0 then HealthPoints = 0 end
        if TempHP < 0 then TempHP = 0 end
        if statsop == "True" then 
            hpinput:SetText(HealthPoints)
            armorinput:SetText(ArmorPoints)
            thpinput:SetText(TempHP) end


--apdmg = Armor point Damage
--hpdmg = Health Point damage
--bdmg = Barrier Damage
--TempHP is also a version of barrier damage.
```

However when i add this to the addon, and try to activate the function I get the following error message.

[image]

Note: Line 1666 is the following

```
block:SetScript("OnClick", function()
    C_Timer.After(1, function()
    --d20 = tonumber(roll)
    d20t = d20 + Block + DefMod
    if d20t >= DifficultyCheckDef then
        OutC = "Pass" else
    OutC = "Fail"
end
```

and line 1634 is simply this

```
apinput:SetText(ArmorPoints)
```

Comment: I fail to see the error message.

Comment: The in game screenshot posted in the bottom of the post -is- the error message that !debugger spits out

Comment: The image didn't load for me at first. Well, apparently, `apinput` is `nil`. You should check where it is initialized. Also, 8 lines you reference as "line 1666" do not form a correct lua block, neither do I see any connection between them, the "line 1634" and the topmost snippet.

Comment: armorinput:SetText(ArmorPoints)
  end)
  HPTX = statsbg:CreateFontString(nil, "High", "GameTooltipText")
  HPTX:SetPoint("RIGHT",armorsub,"LEFT",3,0)
  HPTX:SetText("Armor:")
  HPTX:SetFont("Fonts\\FRIZQT__.ttf", 8,"OUTLINE")

And the end of defining the button for armor it self is the only place where I can find ArmorInput being initialized.

Comment: You can edit your question text. If the code you've added is the ending of "line 1666" then it is still not valid lua block (only two `end`s and three open-ing verbs) and there's still no mention of `apinput`.

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/ou0t2gk4/) is not an answer but I thought that the formula might help.